# I need a to build a chart/graph with Apps Script that looks like one I hand made in googe sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, charts

So below is a dynamic graph this I made directly in google sheets. It updates automatically. So when I want to create a report, I use Apps Script to convert it to an image and copy it into a google doc.

[image]

Here’s my problem: The graph above represents a cummulative graph based on date ranges that the user picks.

What I now need is to creted daily graphs within that range to break these statistics down by day. Because I never know how many days will be in the range that they specify, I have to build these graphs programmatically then insert them into the google sheet.

I have figured out how to do this, but the closest I’ve been able to get in making the daily graphs look like the one above is shown below:

[image]

I simply cannot find the information I need to make the second chart look similar to the first one. Anyone have advice that might help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy your existing chart and modify its properties to generate a new chart.

**Sample Code:**

```
function insertChart(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet5");

  var charts = sheet.getCharts();

  for(var i in charts){

    if(charts[i].getOptions().get('title')== 'Types of Incidents Over Time'){
      var chart = charts[i];
      var modifiedChart = chart
          .modify()
          .clearRanges()
          .addRange(sheet.getRange("A25:B29"))
          .setOption('title','New Chart')
          .setOption('vAxis.gridlines', {minSpacing: 2})
          .setOption('vAxis.minorGridlines.count', 1)
          .setPosition(25,5,0,0)
          .build();
        
      sheet.insertChart(modifiedChart);
    }
    
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

---

### What it does?

1. Get all the existing chart in a specific sheet using [Sheet.getCharts()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getcharts)
2. Select your desired chart based on its chart title using [EmbeddedChart.getOptions()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart#getoptions) and [ChartOptions.get(option)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/chart-options.html#getoption). For a list of available options for Column Chart, please refer [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#configuration-options).
3. Once your desired chart was selected, you can modify the properties of the selected chart using [EmbeddedChart.modify()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart#modify). It will return an [EmbeddedChartBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart-builder) where you can configure your chart's properties. See [EmbeddedChartBuilder Methods](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart-builder#methods) for additional information

> In the sample code, I cleared the existing range first before setting a new data range. After that, I configured some chart options such as the Title, Vertical Axis Gridlines Minspacing, Position, etc.
>
> Note: I had to configured the `vAxis.gridlines` minspacing manually since when I tried to get the `vAxis.gridlines` of the existing chart it returned a `null` value. Chart Options details are discussed [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#configuration-options).

4. Once you have configured your chart, you need to build chart to reflect all changes made to it using [EmbeddedChartBuilder.build()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart-builder#build) which will create an [EmbeddedChart](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart)
5. Insert your newly created [EmbeddedChart](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart) using [Sheet.insertChart(chart)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertchartchart)

Comment: Thank you Ron. I ended up doing something similar to this, but I found your answer helpful in the extreme; especially for filling in some remaining gaps in my knowledge. I appreciate it.